# UIViewController transition from left to right beneath another UIViewControler

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a container UIViewController with a child that acts as a menu. This loads the other child UIViewController. I would like the other UIViewControllers to animate in and out behind the menu which is semi-transparent. I have only been able to make it work when the other children are above the menu (shorter than the entire screen so menu has room on the bottom) but have not achieved a sliding effect behind the menu. Is this effect possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are adding `menuController view` and `new viewController view's` as **subViews** to `containerViewController view`.

First add that new `viewcontroller view` as child to `containerView's view`.
Now that view will be on top of menu's view.
Now bring the menu view to top by

```
[containerView bringSubViewToFront:menuView];
```

Above instruction makes menu view to be on top of sliding viewController's view.Now do the sliding animation on `new viewController's view`.